# GEM5 - Significance of fastmem in GEM5 while creating Simpoints/Checkpoints

Tags: gem5

While looking for how to do Simpoint analysis I found out that you need to run the following command for generating basic block vectors as the first step

% build/ARM/gem5.opt  configs/example/se.py --simpoint-profile --simpoint-interval 10000000 --cpu-type=AtomicSimpleCPU --fastmem

but in the latest version of gem5, I see that the fastmem and its related code has been removed. Could someone tell me the significance of fastmem and would it matter if we generated the bbv without --fastmem?

Comment: Fastmem has been substituted by NonCachingSimpleCPU. The original commit's description answers your question: https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/12419 (719eb033fe435133abf15501c249eec10d1c861f). In your case, just switch "--cpu-type=AtomicSimpleCPU --fastmem" to "--cpu-type=NonCachingSimpleCPU" and it should work. In theory there should be no problem with generating the bbv without fastmem.